# python + firebase + google endpoints

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication

suppose my code is like:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

from google.appengine.ext import ndb

from main import Save

import firebase_admin

query = Save.query().fetch()

print(query)

for q in query: 

    user = auth.create_user( firstname = q.firstname,   \
    lastname =  q.lastname, email = q.email,            \
    password = q.password )
```

it is giving error
ImportError: No module named google.auth

Comment: Are you using App Engine to deploy this application? In such case, are you using Standard or Flexible? And the error you saw was when you tested locally or once deployed to App Engine?